# Linkando dados vindos de duas tabelas diferentes

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho duas tabelas de banco de dados uma chamada cliente, outra municipio, e na tabela "cliente" tenho os itens (CdCliente, NmCliente, Status e CdMunicipio), na tabela "municipio" tenho (CdMunicipio e NmMunicipio).

Quero fazer um link apenas no item "CdMunicipio" na tabela cliente, para quando eu clicar no código de um municipio qualquer na tabela cliente, ele me adicionar automaticamente o municipio que contém esse código na tabela "municipio". Essas tabelas são de um projeto Java com JDBC/JSF, PrimeFaces.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1 - CÓDIGO CLIENTE JAVA

```
package Entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCdCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cdCliente = :cdCliente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByNmCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nmCliente = :nmCliente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByInStatus", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.inStatus = :inStatus"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCdMunicipio", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cdMunicipio = :cdMunicipio")})
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Cd_Cliente")
    private Integer cdCliente;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "Nm_Cliente")
    private String nmCliente;
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "In_Status")
    private String inStatus;
    @Column(name = "Cd_Municipio")
    private Integer cdMunicipio;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Cliente(Integer cdCliente) {
        this.cdCliente = cdCliente;
    }

    public Integer getCdCliente() {
        return cdCliente;
    }

    public void setCdCliente(Integer cdCliente) {
        this.cdCliente = cdCliente;
    }

    public String getNmCliente() {
        return nmCliente;
    }

    public void setNmCliente(String nmCliente) {
        this.nmCliente = nmCliente;
    }

    public String getInStatus() {
        return inStatus;
    }

    public void setInStatus(String inStatus) {
        this.inStatus = inStatus;
    }

    public Integer getCdMunicipio() {
        return cdMunicipio;
    }

    public void setCdMunicipio(Integer cdMunicipio) {
        this.cdMunicipio = cdMunicipio;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (cdCliente != null ? cdCliente.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Cliente)) {
            return false;
        }
        Cliente other = (Cliente) object;
        if ((this.cdCliente == null && other.cdCliente != null) || (this.cdCliente != null && !this.cdCliente.equals(other.cdCliente))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entidades.Cliente[ cdCliente=" + cdCliente + " ]";
    }

}
```

1.1 - CÓDIGO CREATE.XHTML CLIENTE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateClienteTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <div align="center">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            </div>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:20%; margin:auto;" columnClasses="alignTop">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateClienteLabel_cdCliente}" for="cdCliente" />
                    <h:inputText id="cdCliente" value="#{clienteController.selected.cdCliente}" title="#{bundle.CreateClienteTitle_cdCliente}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateClienteRequiredMessage_cdCliente}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateClienteLabel_nmCliente}" for="nmCliente" />
                    <h:inputText id="nmCliente" value="#{clienteController.selected.nmCliente}" title="#{bundle.CreateClienteTitle_nmCliente}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateClienteLabel_inStatus}" for="inStatus" />
                    <h:inputText id="inStatus" value="#{clienteController.selected.inStatus}" title="#{bundle.CreateClienteTitle_inStatus}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateClienteLabel_cdMunicipio}" for="cdMunicipio" />
                    <h:inputText id="cdMunicipio" value="#{clienteController.selected.cdMunicipio}" title="#{bundle.CreateClienteTitle_cdMunicipio}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{clienteController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateClienteSaveLink}" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{clienteController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateClienteShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.CreateClienteIndexLink}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

2 - CÓDIGO MUNICIPIO JAVA

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package Entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author Dani
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCdCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cdCliente = :cdCliente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByNmCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nmCliente = :nmCliente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByInStatus", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.inStatus = :inStatus"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByCdMunicipio", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.cdMunicipio = :cdMunicipio")})
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Cd_Cliente")
    private Integer cdCliente;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "Nm_Cliente")
    private String nmCliente;
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "In_Status")
    private String inStatus;
    @Column(name = "Cd_Municipio")
    private Integer cdMunicipio;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Cliente(Integer cdCliente) {
        this.cdCliente = cdCliente;
    }

    public Integer getCdCliente() {
        return cdCliente;
    }

    public void setCdCliente(Integer cdCliente) {
        this.cdCliente = cdCliente;
    }

    public String getNmCliente() {
        return nmCliente;
    }

    public void setNmCliente(String nmCliente) {
        this.nmCliente = nmCliente;
    }

    public String getInStatus() {
        return inStatus;
    }

    public void setInStatus(String inStatus) {
        this.inStatus = inStatus;
    }

    public Integer getCdMunicipio() {
        return cdMunicipio;
    }

    public void setCdMunicipio(Integer cdMunicipio) {
        this.cdMunicipio = cdMunicipio;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (cdCliente != null ? cdCliente.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Cliente)) {
            return false;
        }
        Cliente other = (Cliente) object;
        if ((this.cdCliente == null && other.cdCliente != null) || (this.cdCliente != null && !this.cdCliente.equals(other.cdCliente))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entidades.Cliente[ cdCliente=" + cdCliente + " ]";
    }

}
```

2.1 - CÓDIGO CREATE.XHTML MUNICIPIO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <div align="center">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            </div>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:20%; margin:auto;" columnClasses="alignTop">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioLabel_cdMunicipio}" for="cdMunicipio" />
                    <h:inputText id="cdMunicipio" value="#{municipioController.selected.cdMunicipio}" title="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioTitle_cdMunicipio}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioRequiredMessage_cdMunicipio}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioLabel_nmMunicipio}" for="nmMunicipio" />
                    <h:inputText id="nmMunicipio" value="#{municipioController.selected.nmMunicipio}" title="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioTitle_nmMunicipio}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{municipioController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioSaveLink}" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{municipioController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.CreateMunicipioIndexLink}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

Comment: Você deseja adicionar esse município em que local? Explique melhor o que pretende!

Comment: É seguinte por exemplo na primeira tabela quero clicar no numero 2 do CdMunicipio do NmCliente (Joimilte Antonio) e ele abrir um browser (ou outra página) onde contém o código e o nome do municipio.

Comment: Já tentou passar o id como parâmetro para outra página para busca  no banco e  gerar a página dinamicamente?

Comment: Quando você clicar no código do munícipio, vc quer que automaticamente seja incluido o código desse municipio e o nome na tabela municipio? Mas como você vai obter o nome do município? Já existe outra tabela com o relacionamento código/nome do municipio?

Comment: Não é mais facil vc ter usado um atributo `Municipio municipio` ao invés de `Integer cdMunicipio` e deixar a manipulação pro JDBC?

Comment: Gente ele só quer que venha carregado o Municipio dentro de Cliente, it's not that hard.

Comment: As anotações que você utilizou na classe de modelo são para projetos que usam algum ORM, como Hibernate, Ebean, TopLink. Com JDBC tais anotações se tornam inúteis.

Comment: Qual o sentido em ter que clicar no código do município? Reconstrua sua classe de acordo com a recomendação do Gustavo Cinque e ao invés de carregar o atributo CdMunicipio na tabela de clientes, use o atributo NmMunicipio.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pelas dicas. A verdade é que o projeto é um crud jsf com primefaces. O que eu queria parece ser simples mas não estou conseguindo fazer, que é clicar num link e abrir uma janela externa (como por exemplo clicar num codigo de cliente e abrir uma janela com o nome do cliente onde eu possa inserir, editar, deletar ou salvar e enviar para banco de dados).